# Отображение окна в соответствии с данными из файла настроек на Си

Tags: c, winapi

При получении `WM_CREATE` читаю из файла настроек, кроме прочего, координаты и размеры окна проги. Как организовать отображение окна по полученным значениям? Предпологаю, что при получении `WM_PAINT` надо вызвать какую-то функцию, например `SetWindowPos()`? Хотелось бы подробный ответ, а то я новичок.

Answer (score 1):

Не надо никакого `WM_PAINT`. Прямо там, в обработчике `WM_CREATE` и делайте `SetWindowPos` с вашими координатами и размерами.

Comment: Я попробовал как Вы советуете, `SetWindowPos (  Hwnd,  HWND_TOP,  500,  500,  500,  500,  SWP_SHOWWINDOW  );`, но окно выводится прямоугольным, почти в левом углу.

Comment: Нет, всё правильно выводится, я поначалу ошибся, извините.